Does anyone know how to configure libcamera-vid to work with imx519
Please could someone look over this and tell me where I am going wrong, or point me in the right direction?
I have an Arducam camera (imx519) attached to a raspberry pi zero 2w and I am trying to pipe the video stream to a server.
The code (someone elses) works with a different camera and raspivid but I am trying to change it to work with the imx519 and libcamera-vid.
I have searched high and low for a definitive list of libcamera options/commands but have not found a complete list anywhere.
On the server I can see the fps rate changing so it is talking, but there is no video. The command I am using is:

libcamera-vid --width ${config.video.width} --height ${config.video.height} -t 0 --framerate ${fps} --bitrate ${bitrate} --analoggain 1.0 --ev 0 --o - --nopreview -n | socat - udp-sendto:${config.host}:${config.port_udp},shut-none'

The errors I get are:

[LTE-Car Error]: [Streamer Error]: [5:16:22.687593899] [1299]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.0+4367-ad9428b4
[LTE-Car Error]: [Streamer Error]: [5:16:22.782643944] [1302]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:444 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx519@1a to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[5:16:22.782763475] [1302]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1101 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
[LTE-Car Error]: [Streamer Error]: Mode selection:
SRGGB10_CSI2P 1280x720 - Score:
[LTE-Car Error]: [Streamer Error]: 3456.67
SRGGB10_CSI2P 1920x1080 - Score: 3706.67
SRGGB10_CSI2P 2328x1748 - Score: 3813.58
SRGGB10_CSI2P 3840x2160 - Score: 28448.5
SRGGB10_CSI2P 4656x3496 - Score: 46829.5
Stream configuration adjusted
[LTE-Car Error]: [Streamer Error]: [5:16:22.797359924] [1299]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 480x360-YUV420 (1) 1280x720-SRGGB10_CSI2P
[5:16:22.798329767] [1302]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:572 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx519@1a - Selected sensor format: 1280x720-SRGGB10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1280x720-pRAA

I think the error is in the libcamera-vid options but I can't figure out what I need to change or add.
Can somebody please point me in the right direction or help me to understand the errors?
Many thanks.
The rest of the code works fine so I have left it alone, I have only altered the libcamera line of code.
